# Calculating price per square inch of a pizza in Java

Tags: java

I am writing a java program to calculate the area of of a pizza in one method and to calculate the price per square inch of a pizza in another method. I have the area method working, but am not getting any output when I try to calculate the price per square inch. I think it has something to do with calling the area() method in the ppsi method, but I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong or how to correctly call the area method.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Pizza {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.out.println("What is the size of your pizza in inches?");
        System.out.println(area() + " square inches");
        System.out.println("What is the price of your pizza?");
        System.out.println(ppsi());
    }

    public static double area(){
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        double diameter = keyboard.nextDouble();
        return (diameter / 2) * (diameter / 2) * Math.PI;

    }
    public static double ppsi(){
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        double price = keyboard.nextDouble();
        return((area()) / price);
    }

}
```

Comment: You're asking for the area again in the `area` method - ask for these values separately and then pass them to the methods as parameters

Comment: @MadProgrammer what do you mean by asking for these values separately? I compute each in their own method.

Comment: Get the value calculated using area() and pass the value to ppsi(double area) and use it instead of area() in ppsi

Comment: You call `area` from within `ppsi`, which will prompt the user AGAIN for the required area.  Prompt for these values externally to the methods and pass the results in as parameters to the method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `ppsi` method, it calls `area`, which is going to prompt the user to enter ANOTHER value in AGAIN.  Instead, prompt for these values first, then pass them into your method

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("What is the size of your pizza in inches?");
    double diameter = keyboard.nextDouble();
    System.out.println(area(diameter) + " square inches");
    double price = keyboard.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("What is the price of your pizza?");
    System.out.println(ppsi(diameter, price));
}

public static double area(double diameter){
    //Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    //double diameter = keyboard.nextDouble();
    return (diameter / 2) * (diameter / 2) * Math.PI;

}
public static double ppsi(double diameter, double price){
    //Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    //double price = keyboard.nextDouble();
    return((area(diameter)) / price);
}
```

This way, the methods are doing ONE job, not two

Answer (score 1):

You are calling area again in **ppsi** method , why does you need it again to read?

I think you want some thing like below , i just modified your code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What is the size of your pizza in inches?");
    double inches=scanner.nextDouble();
    double area=area(inches);
    System.out.println(area + " square inches");
    System.out.println("What is the price of your pizza?");
    double price=scanner.nextDouble();
    System.out.println(ppsi(area, price));
}

public static double area(double diameter){
    return (diameter / 2) * (diameter / 2) * Math.PI;

}
public static double ppsi(double area, double price){
    return((area) / price);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After you print the prompt for "what is the price..." Your program is expecting the user to enter a price, and then enter area again. If you enter two numbers after that prompt, I expect you'll see some output.

Comment: Thank you, I did see output. How do I remedy that so I only have to input that each one time?